# Using entity framework with cassandra database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, cassandra

I am working on a new project which is to use **Asp.net MVC 5** and **Cassandra**.

I am very OK working with entity framework.

Is there a way of connecting entity framework to a Cassandra database?

If not, can anyone help me with the necessary structures to have my MVC 5 application work with a Cassandra database?

More especially is the fact that i want to work with the MVC 5 identity.

I'll really appreciate any help.

Comment: since cassandra is a nosql... EF cant support it... You can use LINQ with cassandra.. see it https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.5/csharp-driver/reference/linqComponent.html

Comment: Oh ok. But is there a ORM to use for the Cassandra?

Comment: as far as i know.. there is no ORM for .NET for cassandra

Comment: What about asp.net identity? Can it be tuned to target a cassandra database?

Comment: i didn't try it but there is a nuget package .. see here https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Identity.Cassandra/

Comment: The DataStax C# driver provides an object mapper: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/csharp-driver-cassandra-new-mapper-linq-improvements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the old versions of EF, up to version 6.x, don't support NoSQL databases like Cassandra.

EF7 is still under development, but it's being designed to be flexible enough to support NoSQL databases. As of today, (Nov 2015) there isn't still any support for a NoSQL database in the current EF7 beta8. But we can expect to see it in the future.

For example you can see it mentioned in this article of MSDN magazine: [Looking ahed to Entity Framework 7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890367.aspx):

> #### Beyond Relational
>
> When Entity Framework was first introduced, Microsoft had a vision of it being used for a variety of data stores, though the first pass focused on relational databases. Non-relational databases existed at that time, but were not widely used, unlike the NoSQL databases—especially document databases—that are so popular today.
>
> While EF is an Object Relational Mapper (ORM), developers who use it want to be able to use the same constructs to interact with non-relational databases. EF7 will provide a high level of support for this, but keep in mind what high level really means. There are vast differences between relational databases and non-relational databases and EF will not make any attempt to mask those differences. But for basic querying and updates, you’ll be able to use the patterns with which you’re already familiar.

Comment: Oh ok. That's some insight

Comment: So what options can be considered for an mvc and cassandra project? I mean in terms of ORM and how to fix the user authentication gap?

Comment: I'd reommend datastax driver, but go to nuget.org, look for Cassandra. You'll see several results, see how many downloads they have, how frequenly and recently have been updated, what functionalities they offer, and how well they are docuemented. I can obly give you this advice. And, I don't recommend you asking at SO, because this kind of "recommend me a library" shpuld be marked for deletion.